# dart mdv databinding does not update on change

Tags: dart, polymer

I am trying to get databinding to work in dart. Basically im doing the same as in this [video](http://dartcasts.com/post/57698566061/episode-16-polymer-dart-setting-up-mdv-using%20video). Using pseudo code it looks like this:

```
mdv.init();
var p = new Person('john');
query('#someId').model = p;
```

In the html file i also have a template which works correctly. For now i am only trying to get one way databinding to work and although the template is correctly initialized, subsequent changes to the variable p are not visible in the template. I tried to trigger an update like this

```
node.model = null;
node.model = p;
```

This does not trigger an update however. But if i'm using a delay it does work:

```
node.model = null;
new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds:20),(){ 
  node.model = p;
});
```

So i have a couple of questions about this:

1. Why does a change in the variable not reflect a change in the template ?
2. Is the template not supposed to update the way i'm doing it? Or is mdv/polymer not working the way it is intended?
3. Is it possible manually trigger an update of the template?
4. Would it be possible to easily convert one-way to two-way databinding (i.e. by making the Person class in the psuedocode observable or something)?

PS i searched and tried several things before posting here. I found a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263845/observable-field-and-text-input-in-polymer?rq=1) in which a custom polymer element is created, which seems more of an hassle then i would like it to be. I also tried the fancy-syntax lib (this did't improve it) and databinder (compile error). I also read a couple of pages about [polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html), but i'm not sure what is relevant to dart and has not been deprecated (or 'stale' as the warning above the page mentions).

Answer (score 0):

You need one of the following packages, to update bindings automatically on change.

- [mdv_observe](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdv_observe)
- [observe](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/observe)

[documentation (Observables)](https://www.dartlang.org/web-ui/observables/)

I would still recommend you to just add "polymer" as a dependency (remove mdv) to your pubspec.yaml. This way you won't have to handle version issues and you would have a guarantee of a "confirmed" set of packages working together.